# Foreach not valid for HashMaps? and general Priority queue question

Tags: parsing, foreach, maps, hashmap, priority-queue

```
public static void Dijk(HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> map, String go, String stop){
   PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue();
    for (String x: map){

    }

  }
```

Why is the complier telling me I can't use a foreach loop here?

Also this is smaller section of a large program but I haven't had much experience with priority queues I want to use it to hold a `<String, int> //or Integer` am I doing this right? (Im using the PQ as a binary heap essentially) (this method will be implementing Dijkstra's algorithm)

Thank you for your help/answers in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you intend to iterate over the keys of the HashMap, you should try

```
for (String x: map.keySet()){

}
```

As for the priority queue, take a look at the Java collection [PriorityQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

Comment: Sorry It's been a very long day, but yes I'm not sure where my head is at thank you! My main concern was getting at the keys. Also with the Priority queue set as it is will it take (String, Integers) when I add to it? I tried casting it like you would a map but it wouldn't compile.

Comment: Can you provide a code example / more clear explanation of what your trying to do?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm
 if you look at the pseudo code section you will see what I'm trying to do basically. The overall goal is to find the shortest path through a word ladder. The main map contains the dictionary and the submap of each element has the neighbors and the distance they are from the key. Then Dijkstra needs to move through them one at a time to find the shortest path to change the start word to the target.        I know how to solve the problem though I believe I just wanted to know the syntax for a PQ of (String, int)

Comment: PriorityQueue<Map<String, Integer>> pq = new  PriorityQueue<Map<String, Integer>>(); pq.add(new HashMap<String, Integer>());

Comment: Thanks again! I always have more trouble with the syntax then the solution!                                                                       --edit--                                                              One question will that create a new map for each entry in the PQ?

Comment: the overall effectual functionality I want is pq.add(String, Integer) doing it that way I will need a name/label for each map within the pq and then a string, int. ie the way you suggested its like pq.add(mapname.put(String, int)) which isn't what I want to be doing.